# Override DENY permission on lower level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, security

I am on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I had to DENY VIEW DEFINITION on database level for a user.

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION TO myUser1;
```

That works, as myUser1 is no longer get back any rows when querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

The problem, is that myUser1 still need to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS view but not to be able to access to any other INFORMATION SCHEMA views.

If I issue REVOKE, or GRANT back VIEW DEFINITION permission on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS, the user still cannot get back any rows.
I understand that there is a DENY on higher level, which override whatever I do on lower level.
Still, is there a way around?
Having the DENY VIEW DEFINITION on DB level, and just overriding it for one particular INFORMATION_SCHEMA view?

Thank you
Joe

Comment: The DENY always overrides a GRANT, no matter if you place it at a lower level or a higher level (the only exception I know is if the user belongs to the sysadmin role, in this case denies are not considered at all). So I think the best option would be to place the DENY only on those specific INFORMATION_SCHEMA views that are problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't override a deny, but I *can* override the lack of a grant.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getDefinitions
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[PARAMETERS] AS [p];
END
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE signingCert
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'gr00vyp@ss!'
    WITH SUBJECT = 'Code signing certificate',
    EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-01-01'
GO
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.[getDefinitions] 
    BY CERTIFICATE signingCert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'gr00vyp@ss!'
CREATE USER viewDefinitionUser FROM CERTIFICATE signingCert
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO viewDefinitionUser
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.[getDefinitions] TO [foobar];
go
```

Where 'foobar' is the actual user that you want to be able to view the parameter information. Essentially, you get elevated permissions (whatever permissions are granted to the user associated with the signing certificate) within the context of the procedure.

Comment: interesting workaround, but a bit too much. If there is a lack of grant, then why granting is not working?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you were willing to grant view definition for this user, this whole scenario goes away. The point is that you can control *how* they view tables in the information_schema schema this way.